How do I write the following symbol in latex?
I tried writing the LaTeX formula $\overleftarrow{\underline{U}}$, but it renders in italics which is not what I am looking for.

If you dont want to add anything to your preamble
$\overleftarrow{\underline{\textrm{U}}}$

BTW, Text in math mode is defaulted to italics in latex
Source

You can use the mathrm tag like this: \overleftarrow{\underline{\mathrm{U}}}.
This renders:
 or , if you're on dark mode :)
Make sure that in the LaTeX document preamble, you have:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

